# Cython used with async - Decorators can only be followed by functions or classes

Tags: python, cython, python-asyncio

I'm trying to compile Python 3 code using Cython (version `0.24.1`). The code heavily depends on `asyncio` and works normally when run with latest Python. Compilation however gives me following error:

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...

    @helpers.json_handler(logger = logger)
    async def get_index(req, req_body):
   ^
------------------------------------------------------------

skystore/mem_node.py:40:4: Decorators can only be followed by functions or classes
```

Does it mean, that async and await keywords are not supported? I thought otherwise because according to [changelog](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/74335c2b0ebc9a46f7ef234079f611999f361874/CHANGES.rst) it was implemented last year.

Comment: It may mean that decorators like `@helpers.json_handler` may not be applied to coroutines `async def function(...)`

Comment: You mean may not be applied when using Cython or in general? Because as I wrote, when run using latest Python, the codes works flawlessly.

Comment: In case of Cython at least, [Parsing.py](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/master/Cython/Compiler/Parsing.py#L387-L403)

Comment: I see. What am I supposed to do then? File an issue?

Comment: Does `get_index = helpers.json_handler(get_index)` work? Because if it does then it should be the same as a decorator. Filing an issue would probably be a good idea anyway though.